# Minimise a function in Python

Tags: python, scipy-optimize-minimize

Could you help on how to minimize a function in Python? Particularly, it's the logistic function. Below is my cost function, I got it correctly because I checked the answer.

```
def g(z):

  h = 1 / (1 + numpy.exp(-z))
  return h

theta1_ravel = theta1.ravel().T
theta2_ravel = theta2.ravel().T

theta_conca = numpy.concatenate((theta1_ravel, theta2_ravel))
lambada = 1

def computecost(theta_conca):

  theta1 = numpy.reshape(theta_conca[0:10025], (25, 401))
  theta2 = numpy.reshape(theta_conca[10025:10285], (10, 26))

  a1 = X_1
  a2 = g(X_1 * theta1.T) # (5000, 25)
  a2 = numpy.column_stack((numpy.ones((m, 1)), a2))
  a3 = g(a2 * theta2.T) # (5000, 10)

  reg_term = (lambada / (2*m)) * (numpy.sum(numpy.power(theta1[:, 1:], 2)) + numpy.sum(numpy.power(theta2[:, 1:], 2)))

  J = -(1/m) * (numpy.sum(numpy.multiply(Y, numpy.log(a3)) + numpy.multiply((1 - Y), numpy.log(1 - a3)))) + reg_term

  return J

J = computecost(theta_conca)
J
```

And then I try to minimize it, get theta by using "scipy.optimize.minimize" but it's not working.

```
theta_random = numpy.random.rand(m, 1)
theta_random
scipy.optimize.minimize(computecost, theta_random)
```

This is the error notification:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-05051c7a9e1f> in <module>
      1 theta_random = numpy.random.rand(m, 1)
      2 theta_random
----> 3 scipy.optimize.minimize(computecost, theta_random)

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py in minimize(fun, x0, args, method, jac, hess, hessp, bounds, constraints, tol, callback, options)
    592         return _minimize_cg(fun, x0, args, jac, callback, **options)
    593     elif meth == 'bfgs':
--> 594         return _minimize_bfgs(fun, x0, args, jac, callback, **options)
    595     elif meth == 'newton-cg':
    596         return _minimize_newtoncg(fun, x0, args, jac, hess, hessp, callback,

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py in _minimize_bfgs(fun, x0, args, jac, callback, gtol, norm, eps, maxiter, disp, return_all, **unknown_options)
    996     else:
    997         grad_calls, myfprime = wrap_function(fprime, args)
--> 998     gfk = myfprime(x0)
    999     k = 0
   1000     N = len(x0)

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py in function_wrapper(*wrapper_args)
    325     def function_wrapper(*wrapper_args):
    326         ncalls[0] += 1
--> 327         return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
    328 
    329     return ncalls, function_wrapper

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py in approx_fprime(xk, f, epsilon, *args)
    755 
    756     """
--> 757     return _approx_fprime_helper(xk, f, epsilon, args=args)
    758 
    759 

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py in _approx_fprime_helper(xk, f, epsilon, args, f0)
    689     """
    690     if f0 is None:
--> 691         f0 = f(*((xk,) + args))
    692     grad = numpy.zeros((len(xk),), float)
    693     ei = numpy.zeros((len(xk),), float)

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py in function_wrapper(*wrapper_args)
    325     def function_wrapper(*wrapper_args):
    326         ncalls[0] += 1
--> 327         return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
    328 
    329     return ncalls, function_wrapper

<ipython-input-33-3761d25f71af> in computecost(theta_conca)
     14 def computecost(theta_conca):
     15 
---> 16     theta1 = numpy.reshape(theta_conca[0:10025], (25, 401))
     17     theta2 = numpy.reshape(theta_conca[10025:10285], (10, 26))
     18 

<__array_function__ internals> in reshape(*args, **kwargs)

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in reshape(a, newshape, order)
    299            [5, 6]])
    300     """
--> 301     return _wrapfunc(a, 'reshape', newshape, order=order)
    302 
    303 

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
     59 
     60     try:
---> 61         return bound(*args, **kwds)
     62     except TypeError:
     63         # A TypeError occurs if the object does have such a method in its

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 5000 into shape (25,401)
```

How can I implement it? I'm sorry that the code looks like a mess but I think I shouldn't cut off something. I'll give you the entire code and data if you need to try on your device.

Thank you.

Comment: in `computecost` you use `theta_conca[10025:10285]` so you need data with size at least `10285`  but you try to use data with size `5000` (it seems `m` has value `5000`) - `theta_random = numpy.random.rand(10285, 1)`

Comment: python_user: Thank you. I didn't know that.

Comment: furas: Thank you, I edited my "theta_coca" with the size 10285. But it runs too slow and causes lags. I had to turn off and restart my laptop. Do you know how to address this?